# I cant access <asp:textbox> value in code behind file

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Good Morning

I have a webpage with a button pad on it. It is used at a gas station with bad network so everytime they click on the button to add a number to the textbox it will load forever so I changed the button clicks to javascript.

It works perfectly but now the code behind gets an empty value (Not null) when i retrieve the value from the textbox.

This is my code

The buttons used to add the numbers to the textbox
and the textbox

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="OVKWEBAPP.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <title></title>

    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstyle.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    .modal
    {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        /*background-color: black;*/
        z-index: 99;
        opacity: 0.8;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .loading
    {

        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
        border: 5px solid #67CFF5;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: White;
        z-index: 999;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRknr" runat="server" CssClass="txtBoxRknr" PlaceHolder="Rekening Nommer" Enabled="False" autocomplete="off" Width="175px"></asp:TextBox>
        <input type="button" id="btnPad1" runat="server" value="1" class="buttonsb" onclick="input(this);"/>
        <input type="button" id="btnPad2" runat="server" value="2" class="buttonsb" onclick="input(this);"/>
        <asp:Button ID="btnMsg1" runat="server" Text="Gaan Voort" CssClass="buttonsa" OnClick="btnMsg1_Click" />
    </form>
</body> 

<script type="text/javascript">     
function input(e) {
        document.getElementById("<%=txtRknr.ClientID %>").value = document.getElementById("<%=txtRknr.ClientID %>").value + e.value;
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

And this is my code in the code behind file

```
        protected void btnMsg1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblError.Text = "";
            //string user = txtRknr.Text;
            string user = ((TextBox)FindControl("txtRknr")).Text;
            if(user == "")
            //if (txtRknr.Text == "")
            {
                lblError.Text = "ONGELDIGE REKENING NOMMER";
                return;
            }
}
```

Basically all this needs to do is add an account number to a textbox from an button pad on the website.

After the account is added they would click on continue button and then the code behind checks if the textbox is empty if it is not empty it connects to database to check if it is valid.

But no matter how many numbers i add to the textbox it is still empty when i access it from code behind.

Comment: Why are you using FindControl? The Control is inside the page and it doesn't look like it's inside another control

Comment: You have disabled the TextBox: `Enabled="False"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Enabled="False"` means that your input field will have a `disabled` attribute. Disabled form elements do not get posted in HTML forms, which means that when you access it from the code-behind, it's using the default value of the textbox.

Try `ReadOnly="True"` instead of `Enabled="False"` if you don't want the field to be edited by hand.

**EDIT**

I guess ASP.NET prevents you from reading the value from a `ReadOnly=True` textbox, to prevent you from doing exactly what you're trying to do. A `<asp:HiddenField>` creates an `<input type="hidden">`, which you should be able to write the value and have it posted properly to the codebehind.

Comment: And if OP is really paranoid about people messing with HTML he can also change TextBox to Label.

Comment: Joe Enos. I removed the Enabled="false" and added ReadOnly="True"

Comment: I still had the same problem though. but when I removed both readonly and enabled it worked. But the website is used on table so i need something like read only  so that the table keyboard does not pop up when the textbox is selected

Thank you for the help so far

Comment: Right, I forgot about that - I think WebForms has a security feature where a `ReadOnly` textbox won't show the value in the codebehind because from its perspective, since it's readonly, you shouldn't be able to modify it, even though it was posted that way. You can probably get it using the `Request.Form` collection, but your best bet is probably a hidden field `<asp:HiddenField>` which will create an `<input type="hidden">`, and that should be able to be edited through javascript, and posted properly. If you still need a visual representation, just do both the textbox and the hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```cs
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="OVKWEBAPP.WebForm1" %>
```

replace in `Inherits="OVKWEBAPP.WebForm1"` with `Inherits="OVKWEBAPP.default"`

Answer (score -3):

try this.

```
Request.Form["by-name-attribute"];
```

Comment: OP wanted to access form posted values in  code behind, I could not notice the Enable="false" attribute. So suggested this answer which works well for access form values in codebehind file